# CentOS RPM database trashed, "rpm --rebuilddb" won't fix, can I recover using /var/lib/rpm/ from a 2nd, identical server?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

My RPM database is shot, neither rpm or yum works.  Supposedly "rpm --rebuilddb" will fix it, but it doesn't in my case.  This server has three sister servers that are basically identical, and have working RPM databases.  I tried copying /var/lib/rpm/ from working server to the sick one, but that didn't fix it.  Any ideas of how I can use good server's rpm to fix the sick one?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing /var/lib/rpm/__db.* before doing an rpm --rebuilddb.

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me.  After some googling, I tried this:

rm /dev/urandom
mknod -m 644 /dev/urandom c 1 9

After that,  rpm --rebuilddb did work.  Unfortunately, I don't know what happened to my /dev/uraqndom. :(

Answer (score 0):

rm /dev/urandom ;mknod -m 644 /dev/urandom c 1 9

works for me as well